# How to define a variable in build.gradle file whose value is passed dynamically by jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, gulp, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a Gradle task 'runRegression' in my build.gradle which is calling a Gulp task 'runEndtoEnd' and passing a parameter 'param1' to it.

```
task runRegression(type: Exec){
  executable "xvfb-run"
  args "gulp", "runEndtoEnd", param1
}
```

The Gradle task is called by jenkins which will pass the value for 'param1' using command:
`gradle runRegression -Pparam1=Dev`

When I execute the command, I can see the gradle task executing the gulp task and pass the parameter to it through 'param1'.
The issue comes when we do a 'gradle build'.
It is not able to resolve the parameter 'param1'.

Getting error:
*A problem occurred evaluating project:.
Could not find property 'param1' on task 'runRegression'.*

Any solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `param1` is not found.  You can get the value sent via `-P` with something like this

```
def myProp = project.hasProperty('param1') ?
        project.getProperty('param1') : null
```

After executing `gradle -Pparam1=dev` the value of `myProp` will be `dev`

Comment: Thanks JBirdVegas.